Whoosh/searching.py name "q" is not defined
I'm using whoosh library version 2.7.4
when trying to use search:
query = rule['parse_tree'].to_whoosh_query()
hits = searcher.search(query, limit = None)

I'm getting an error inside site-package/whoosh/searching.py:
name 'q' is not defined
What could be causing this error?
stack trace:
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-22-caefc8e0229a> in <module>
----> 1 search_results = search_rules(parsed_rules_by_level, df_full)
<ipython-input-5-1a9f0507c3e6> in search_rules(parsed_rules_by_level, df_full, search_dates)
   369                             continue
   370                         query = rule['parse_tree'].to_whoosh_query()
--> 371                         hits = searcher.search(query, limit=None)
   372                         for hit in hits:
   373                             session_id = hit['unique_session_id']

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/whoosh/searching.py in search(self, q, **kwargs)

   784         c = self.collector(**kwargs)
   785         # Call the lower-level method to run the collector
--> 786         self.search_with_collector(q, c)
   787         # Return the results object from the collector
   788         return c.results()

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/whoosh/searching.py in search_with_collector(self, q, collector, context)

   817         collector.prepare(self, q, context)
   818
--> 819         collector.run()
   820
   821     def correct_query(self, q, qstring, correctors=None, terms=None, maxdist=2,

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/whoosh/query/spans.py in estimate_size(self, ixreader)

   558
   559     def estimate_size(self, ixreader):
--> 560         return self._and_query().estimate_size(ixreader)
   561
   562     def estimate_min_size(self, ixreader):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/whoosh/query/spans.py in _and_query(self)
   555
   556     def _and_query(self):
--> 557         return q.And(self.qs)
   558
   559     def estimate_size(self, ixreader):
NameError: name 'q' is not defined


Bugs in a 3rd-party library are generally better reported to the authors of that library. (Regardless -- do include the full stack trace; right now we need to look through the library for codepaths that could cause the problem, whereas the stack trace you're not giving us has an exact line number).

...okay, so it's not whoosh/searching.py with the bug as you first claimed, it's whoosh/query/spans.py... and on its face, that's an actual bug with the library itself, not a place where you're using it wrong.

I suspect that what they want might be something more like: q = self.qs[0]; return q.And(self.qs[1:]) -- of course, that needs checks added before it's actually correct.
